# Excel Interop SaveAs() hangs with huge spreadsheet data

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I try to use SaveAs() to save Excel spreadsheet data (with 8 sheets, some sheets with 15000 rows) but the SaveAS() never returns.  If I remove some sheets it will success to save to hard disk file.  Is there any way I could save the whole huge spreadsheet without hanging?

Thanks a lot.

```
///////// my c# code to save Excel data:
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(outFileName,
                  Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                  Type.Missing,
                  Type.Missing,
                  false,
                  false,
                  Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                  false,
                  false,
                  Type.Missing,
                  Type.Missing,
                  Type.Missing);

xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried running it with `xlApp.Visible = True` to see if Excel is popping up any strange errors?  You can also try `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false` to stop any warnings/errors that might be popping up behind the running application (we've run into both of these problems before)

Comment: It's working with xlApplication.Visible = true.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @CHI KUO TANG ah, that is of course what I meant.  I'll edit my answer to clarify.  I'm glad you were able to get it to work.